# Conflicting versions of Data.Map

Tags: haskell, module

I'm working with this module [Algorithms.Geometry.LineSegmentIntersection.BentleyOttman](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hgeometry-0.6.0.0/docs/Algorithms-Geometry-LineSegmentIntersection-BentleyOttmann.html) using the function "intersections"  that returns something of type **Intersections** which in turn is an alias for **Map (Point 2 r) (Associated p r)**. So, I try to manipulate that result with the corresponding functions of the [Data.Map.Lazy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html) module, but I get the following error:
[image]
Any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You should probably use stack to ensure all dependencies are consistent https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/

Comment: Please paste error messages as text, and not as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two versions of the containers package installed, and have  ended up referencing both of them. A Map produced by containers 0.5.7.1 can't be passed to a Map-consuming function from containers 0.5.10.1 (or any mismatched versions), even if their definition of Map in source code is the same.

Without knowing more about your installation history, it's impossible to say exactly why that happened. I would guess you're just using `cabal install` to install packages as you need them, into the default user-wide package environment? That almost inevitably results in problems like this, eventually.

The easiest immediate solution is to delete your entire store of installed packages and then reinstall everything you need again (preferably all at the same time, not with multiple separate invocations of `cabal install`).

To prevent this from happening again, to could change your work practices to use tools like `cabal sandbox` or `stack`, which facilitate having separate package environments for each project.

Answer (score 1):

Tough to know for sure without more details, but I will assume you are using stack and the latest LTS snapshot (8.6 as of the time I'm writing this).

This could be happening because [LTS 8.6](https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.6) has [containers-0.5.7.1](https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.6/package/containers-0.5.7.1), and you are attempting to use a function that is in a newer version ([containers-0.5.10.1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.1)) which hasn't made its way from Hackage to Stackage yet.

To resolve this, modify your `stack.yaml` file to include:

```
extra-deps:
- containers-0.5.10.1
```

Comment: No, OP clearly has both packages installed which is the problem. They're probably not using stack if they have a conflict like that.